# Uniqueidentifier conversion failed when Importing XML file to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, import

I'm trying to import data from an XML file into a SQL Server table. However, I'm getting the error:

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

It says it's in state 2 of Line 6 (Id3), but I assume the conversion is failing in other places.

**XML:**

```
<ImportExportObject>
  <Objects>
    <MyObject>
      <Id>123e5c8c-a7fc-40da-440e-12348bc612e8</Id>
      <Id2>123e5c8c-a7fc-40da-440e-12348bc612e8</Id2>
      <Name>en</Name>
      <Id3>123e5c8c-a7fc-40da-440e-12348bc612e8</Id3>
    </MyObject>
  </Objects>
</ImportExportObject>
```

**SQL code:**

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(ID, Id2, Name, Id3)
SELECT
   MyXMLDocument.query('Id').value('.', 'uniqueidentifier'),
   MyXMLDocument.query('Id2').value('.', 'uniqueidentifier'),
   MyXMLDocument.query('Name').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
   MyXMLDocument.query('Id3').value('.', 'uniqueidentifier'),
FROM (SELECT CAST(MyXMLDocument AS xml)
      FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\myUser\Documents\MyXMLDocument.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MyXMLDocument)) AS T(MyXMLDocument)
      CROSS APPLY MyXMLDocument.nodes('ImportExportObject/Objects/MyObject') AS MyXMLDocument (MyObject);
```

**How do I resolve this error?**

I've been unable to get Select Cast and Convert to work - and .value() requires string literals so '@Id' doesn't seem to work.

Quite unsure here - any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What's the version of the SQL Server?

Comment: @gotqn it's SQL Server 15.0.2

Answer (score 0):

How about having MyTable with an automatically imported id and not importing that? Would that work for what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can the code below to find which values cannot be converted to `uniqueidentifier`:

```
SELECT
   MyXMLDocument.query('Id').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
   MyXMLDocument.query('Id2').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
   MyXMLDocument.query('Id3').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
FROM (SELECT CAST(MyXMLDocument AS xml)
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\myUser\Documents\MyXMLDocument.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MyXMLDocument)) AS T(MyXMLDocument)
CROSS APPLY MyXMLDocument.nodes('ImportExportObject/Objects/MyObject') AS MyXMLDocument (MyObject)
WHERE TRY_CAST(MyXMLDocument.query('Id').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS uniqueidentifier) IS NULL
    OR TRY_CAST(MyXMLDocument.query('Id2').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS uniqueidentifier) IS NULL
    OR TRY_CAST(MyXMLDocument.query('Id3').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS uniqueidentifier) IS NULL
```

The idea is to use `TRY_CAST` which will return `NULL` if the data cannot be converted.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @x xml = N'<ImportExportObject>
  <Objects>
    <MyObject>
      <Id>123e5c8c-a7fc-40da-440e-12348bc612e8</Id>
      <Id2>123e5c8c-a7fc-40da-440e-12348bc612e8</Id2>
      <Name>en</Name>
      <Id3>123e5c8c-a7fc-40da-440e-12348bc612e8</Id3>
    </MyObject>
  </Objects>
</ImportExportObject>';

SELECT
   MyXML.MyObject.value('Id[1]', 'uniqueidentifier'),
   MyXML.MyObject.value('Id2[1]', 'uniqueidentifier'),
   MyXML.MyObject.value('Name[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
   MyXML.MyObject.value('Id3[1]', 'uniqueidentifier')
FROM 
(
    SELECT @x
    -- CAST(MyXMLDocument AS xml) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\myUser\Documents\MyXMLDocument.xml', SINGLE_BLOB)
) AS T(MyXMLDocument)
CROSS APPLY MyXMLDocument.nodes('./ImportExportObject/Objects/MyObject') AS MyXML(MyObject);
```